# Geodesic curve on an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, ellipsoids

I cannot find my mistake in the statement below, neither computational nor conceptual. I cannot prove that the velocity vector $\dot{x}$ is constant along the acclaimed geodesic. Could you review it for me? Briefly, both verbose and symbolic argumentation are below:

**Verbose argument**: We may represent an ellipsoid $\mathcal{S}$ submerged in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in ellipsoidal coordinates by equality $u_3 = 1$, for coordinate chart $(u, \eta)$ corresponding to horizontal and vertical meridian angles and radius and aforementioned map. It means, in ellipsoidal coordinates, a geodesic curve is a straight line. The geodesic curve $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ in Euclidean coordinates corresponds to this line evaluated in the ellipsoidal transformation map. Since the velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ along a geodesic has constant value, the distance between two coordinates $p, \, q \in \mathcal{S}$ corresponds to the Euclidean norm of velocity vector $\dot{x}$ given by $J_\eta \dot{u}$ evaluated at any coordinate within geodesic parametrization $[0, 1]$. It means that the expression $(\dot{u}^\intercal J_\eta^\intercal)(J_\eta \dot{u})(t)$, for $u(t) = u(0) + t \, (u(1) - u(0))$ must not depend on variable $t$ and is equal to distance map $d(q, \, p)$.

**Mathematical argument**: Given length of each eigen axis to origin are equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_k}}$, the ellipsoid parametrization emerges naturally from ellipsoidal coordinate chart $([0, \, 2 \pi] \times [-\pi, \, \pi] \times  1, \eta)$ given by map. , its vectorial form corresponds to equation below.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:spherical_map}
    \eta(u_1, u_2, u_3) = \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, \underbrace{
        \begin{pmatrix}
            u_3 \, \cos{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} \\
            u_3 \, \sin{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} \\
            u_3 \, \cos{(u_2) }
        \end{pmatrix}
    }_{\sigma(u)}
\end{equation}

Ellipsoidal Cartesian representation $\lambda_1 x_1^2 + \lambda_2 x_2^2 + \lambda_3 x_3^2 - 1 = 0$ turns into equality $u_3 - 1 = \, 0$. Therefore, geodesic curves in chart  coordinate $([0, 2 \, \pi] \times [-\pi, \pi] \times  1, \eta)$ are curvature-free curves whose differential behaviour respects equality $\ddot{c}(t) = 0$ for every instant $t \in [0, 1]$ and 3-tuple $u \, \in \, 1 \times [0, 2 \, \pi] \times [-\pi, \pi]$. The deviation $\delta$ is equal to difference $u(1) - u(0)$ and represents the velocity vector $\dot{u}(t)$.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:line}
    u(t) = p + t \, \delta
\end{equation}

The distance map $d(p, \, q)$ between two coordinates $p$ and $q$ on a smooth surface is given by equation below, for the geodesic velocity vector norm along a geodesic curve.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:geodesic}
    d(p, q) \, = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\langle \dot{c}, \, \dot{c} \rangle} \, dt
\end{equation}

By substitution of velocity vector $\dot{c}$ on equation below as product $J_\eta(u(t)) \, \dot{u}(t)$, the tensor $J(t)$ appears naturally, equal to integral of tensor given by product $J_\eta^\intercal \, J_\eta$ i.e. $J_\sigma^\intercal \, \Lambda^{-1} \, J_\sigma$ evaluated along curve $u(t)$ from $0$ to $1$. Hence, the distance map $d(p, \, q)$ is equal to expression $\delta^\intercal \, J \, \delta$.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:eta_jacobian}
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{\partial \, \eta}{\partial \, u} & = J_\eta = \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, J_\sigma  \\
        & = \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, \begin{pmatrix}
            - u_3 \, \sin{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} & u_3 \, \cos{(u_1)} \, \cos{(u_2)} & \cos{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} \\
            u_3 \, \cos{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} & u_3 \, \sin{(u_1)} \, \cos{(u_2)} & \sin{(u_1)} \, \sin{(u_2)} \\
            0 & - u_3 \, \sin{(u_2)} & \cos{(u_2)}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: You say that there is an error. How do you know? And an error compared to what?

Comment: I cannot prove that the velocity vector $\dot{x}$ is constant along the line curve. Therefore, I suspect there is a mistake.

Comment: Furthermore, the inner product $\langle \dot{c}, \, \dot{c} \rangle$ must not depend on variable $t$.

Comment: The velocity vector of a (constant-speed) geodesic is rarely constant. The acceleration vector, however, must be orthogonal to the surface.

Comment: You’re also very wrong to say “curvature-free curves.” Only their geodesic curvature vanishes. Same mistake.

Comment: I say, in this particular case, the statement is not wrong, since a geodesic indeed maps to a geodesic, case it is true. But I agree with you about curvature-free is a manifold, and not a curve, property.

Comment: A curve, however, is a 1-dimensional manifold.

Comment: I apologize: the velocity vector NORM must not exhibit variable $t$ and be equal to desired function $d(q, p)$.

Comment: had you think in minimize the integral $d(p,q)$ by variational calculus?

Comment: I can just substitute $\dot{u}(t)$ on equaiton $\dot{c} = J_\eta \, \dot{u}$. However, it is too much effort since the velocity vector norm MUST NOT depend on variable $t$...

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to answer.

Comment: You may read the statement once more.

Comment: I have read it two times and cannot really get what you are trying to show either

Comment: I added one last phrase to the verbose argument. Try it now.

Comment: After re-reading this and related a question, my best guess is that you're conflating distinct properties, possibly including: 1. The representation of a path on a surface in local coordinates has constant acceleration, i.e., is a Euclidean line in the plane. (In fact, _every_ regular path in a surface is locally a coordinate curve.) 2.(a) A path has constant velocity; 2.(b) A path has zero acceleration. 3. A path is a geodesic.

Comment: I read this article from Rinow's student Peter Dombrowski: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19680380302. My intention is to use the chart $([0, 2\pi] \times [-\pi, \pi] \times 1, \eta)$ instead of usual Euclidean coordinates to obtain the geodesic curve equation. Conveniently, the ellipsoidal transformation diffeomorphically maps an ellipsoid into a horizontal plane i.e. the same surface in different coordinate representations have different geometric properties.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang about your annotations: 1 2 and 3 are related, for 1 the common option. A geodesic curve has zero acceleration in its velocity vector direction, i.e., its velocity vector has a constant norm. 2a is only true for curvature-free surfaces.

Comment: For what it's worth, it is not true that a path is geodesic if and only if its velocity vector has constant norm (i.e., the path has constant speed). For example, a circle $c(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ in the plane has constant speed, but is not a geodesic. <> It is also not true that a path on a surface has constant velocity if and only if the surface has no curvature: Many non-flat surfaces contain Euclidean lines (hyperboloids, cylinders, saddles, ...).

Comment: Ok, than null covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}$ respective to Levi-Civitta connection satisfies the geodesic curve condition?

Comment: In this setting, yes, a path on a surface is a geodesic if and only if the velocity field is parallel along the path. (Depending on viewpoint, that condition may or may not be the definition.)